# Postgresql query works locally, but fails on Travis CI

Tags: sql, postgresql, travis-ci

This is driving me crazy.  The following query is working totally fine locally, but failing when I test it on travis-ci and throwing the error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 39`

Hopefully, someone can see something I can't.

Here are my tables:

```
+----------+---------------+
|   ways                   |
+----------+---------------+
| way_id   |  bigint       |
| node_ids |  bigint array |
| rep_lat  |  float(9)     |
| rep_lon  |  float(9)     |
+----------+---------------+

+---------+-----------+
|  nodes              |
+---------+-----------+
| node_id |  bigint   |
| lat     |  float(9) |
| lon     |  float(9) |
+---------+-----------+
```

Here is my query:

```
update ways 
set (rep_lat, rep_lon) = 
  ( 
    select lat, lon 
    from nodes 
    where nodes.node_id = ways.node_ids[array_length(ways.node_ids, 1)/2]
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird, for whatever reason, this format was acceptable:

```
UPDATE ways 
SET rep_lat=subq.lat, rep_lon=subq.lon 
FROM (SELECT lat, lon, node_id FROM nodes) as subq 
WHERE subq.node_id = ways.node_ids[array_length(ways.node_ids, 1)/2]
```